# Targeting last child with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have some example post markup:

```
<article class="post">
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>
        <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="#"></a> <!-- TARGET ME (LAST) -->
    </p>
    <p>Some text. Some more text <a href="#">with link</a></p>
    <p>
        <a href="#"><img src="#"></a> <!-- TARGET ME (LAST) -->
    </p>
    <p>Some text. Some more text <a href="#">with link</a></p>
</article>
```

Fiddle of the above can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/4TCyM/

**Question:** How can I target the last image in each set (shown with HTML comments) without changing this markup?

I assume JavaScript will be required, since I can't think of any CSS solution. I can't use `img:last-child` since this targets every image in the above markup. I can't use `a:last-child img` since this wouldn't target anything in the above markup.

Comment: Why do you think `a:last-child img` won't work, see http://jsfiddle.net/4TCyM/5/

Comment: I'm sorry, you're absolutely right. Was staring the answer in the face!

Answer (score 1):

This will do it using jQuery's [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
​$(".post p").find("img:last")​​
```

Alternatively if you must check that they are within an `a` tag you can do:

```
$(".post p").find("a img:last")
```

Also, after just double-checking, your original works too:

```
$("a:last-child img");
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4TCyM/3/)

Answer (score 0):

`$('a:last-child').children('img')` should do the trick. Find the last anchors in each set, then drill into the img tags with `>`, `.children()`, or `.find()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:last-of-type`!

```
p img:last-of-type { ... }
```

or use `:last-child` on the anchor rather than the image:

```
p a:last-child img { ... }
```

No JS needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
​$​("a:last-child").has("img").css("background", "red");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4TCyM/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "article.post p a:last-child img" )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/fUfmY/